# Mystery component identification help

Tags: identification, passive-components

What is the pink axial component in this picture?  The datasheet for the proximal IC suggests it probably is a resistor, but I'm having trouble figuring out it's resistance value given that it doesn't seem to match 5-color band coding.

[image: mystery component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a 0.47Ω 5% resistor. The black band may indicate non-inductive.

Comment: Wow, that is VERY helpful.  Thank you!